# Sufficient statistic and conditional distribution intuition?

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability

I am confused about the intuition behind the definition of a sufficient statistic. The part definition of a sufficient statistic that I am confused about is why the conditional distribution of a sample given the value of the statistic does not depend on the parameter of interest.

I guess this is almost more of a question about conditional distributions maybe. But is there any intuition behind why this makes sense? I understand conditional probability in the sense of events but I am having a hard time understanding why conditioning on the statistic would make this new distribution not depend on the parameter of interest. Does conditioning on a statistic that has all the information about the parameter "remove" that information from the sample? I guess I'm confused about how to conceptually think about conditioning and why it makes sense that the new distribution doesn't depend on the parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea for a sufficient statistic is that:

A sufficient statistic can be a function that can give you all the information to compute any estimate of your parameter.
Now, roughly speaking, conditional distributions given the parameter is actually a function with no unknown parameters,i.e:
$$f(x\mid\theta=2)=2\times\exp(-2x) $$
In this paradeigm $X$ follows the exponential distribution given the parameter value $(=2)$.

So the sufficient statistic has the meaning that for any value of the parameter the conditional distribution of $X\mid T$ is the same.
Is this helpful?

Comment: Yes, this is very helpful! Thank you. I think I'm getting confused about why mathematically the conditional distribution would be equal to the joint of the two divided by the distribution of the statistic. I think the idea of "dividing by a distribution" does not make sense to me and is where I keep thinking about "getting rid" of the parameter by "dividing it out".

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by 'dividing'.

Comment: Well, the formula for calculating a conditional probability is:

f(x|y) = f(x,y)/fy(y) 

Where in our case, I guess fy(y) would be the distribution of the suff statistic? So, I don't understand from that standpoint why we are doing that and how that makes sense intuitively.

Comment: I think that you have a problem with the meaning of conditional distribution and with the understanding of parameters and variables... Maybe this can help you? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic

Comment: Yeah, that's why I posted on here. I don't understand really how the intuitive meaning and mathematical definition relate. What do you mean with parameters and variables?